# JSPs with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jsp

I have been working on a spring-boot project initialized with spring initialzr. The generated package has no `/webapp` directory, hence had to add `/webapp` directory. I have read from spring documentation that spring detects static files from `/static`,`resources`. I have placed 3 different `index.jsp` to test which one gets displayed by my controller. Below are the code snippets.

**Directory Tree:**

```
├── HELP.md
├── mvnw
├── mvnw.cmd
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── com
│   │   │       └── databasedisplay
│   │   │           └── app
│   │   │               ├── AppApplication.java
│   │   │               ├── config
│   │   │               │   ├── WebAppInitializer.java
│   │   │               │   └── WebConfig.java
│   │   │               ├── controller
│   │   │               │   ├── HomeController.java
│   │   │               │   └── IndexController.java
│   │   │               ├── repository
│   │   │               └── ServletInitializer.java
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   │   ├── application.properties
│   │   │   ├── index.jsp
│   │   │   ├── static
│   │   │   │   └── index.jsp
│   │   │   └── templates
│   │   └── webapp
│   │       └── WEB-INF
│   │           └── views
│   │               └── index.jsp
│   └── test
│       └── java
│           └── com
│               └── databasedisplay
│                   └── app
│                       └── AppApplicationTests.java
└── target
    ├── classes
    │   ├── application.properties
    │   ├── com
    │   │   └── databasedisplay
    │   │       └── app
    │   │           ├── AppApplication.class
    │   │           ├── config
    │   │           │   ├── WebAppInitializer.class
    │   │           │   └── WebConfig.class
    │   │           ├── controller
    │   │           │   ├── HomeController.class
    │   │           │   └── IndexController.class
    │   │           └── ServletInitializer.class
    │   ├── index.jsp
    │   └── static
    │       └── index.jsp
    ├── generated-sources
    │   └── annotations
    ├── generated-test-sources
    │   └── test-annotations
    ├── maven-status
    │   └── maven-compiler-plugin
    │       ├── compile
    │       │   └── default-compile
    │       │       ├── createdFiles.lst
    │       │       └── inputFiles.lst
    │       └── testCompile
    │           └── default-testCompile
    │               ├── createdFiles.lst
    │               └── inputFiles.lst
    └── test-classes
        └── com
            └── databasedisplay
                └── app
                    └── AppApplicationTests.class
```

**index.jsp (in '/resources')**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1>This is the body of the sample view in /resources</h1>
</body>
```

**index.jsp (in '/static')**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is the body of the sample view in /static</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.jsp (in '/WEB-INF/views/')**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is the body of the sample view in WEB-INF/views</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/indexA", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

**Configuration Classes**

**WebConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver
                = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable("testServlet");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/").setCachePeriod(3600)
                .resourceChain(true).addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    }


}
```

**WebInitializer.java**

```
    public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        context.scan("com.databasedisplay.app");

        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("mvc", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

The issue is when I run with `mvn spring-boot:run` or `mvn clean package spring-boot:run` the `\target` directory as shown in the directory tree has no `index.jsp` from `\WEB-INF\views\` (in fact the target directory doesn't have a `WEB-INF` directory at all). But I still get the following output when I `curl http://localhost:8080/indexA` :
`This is the body of the sample view in WEB-INF/views`

1. Can someone explain how the view resolver even maps the view names to the corresponding views? (I have looked into `InternalResourceViewResolver` and how to set prefixes and suffixes but that still does not explain how it can render a jsp when it is not in target)
2. Can someone point out to the differences between `mvn spring-boot:run` and `mvn clean package spring-boot:run` as in the latter there is WEB-INF directory in the target.
3. Why am I getting `index.jsp` corresponding to `/WEB-INF` but not other views on `curl`?

Comment: Why would you want to make use of JSP's instead of .HTML and JavaScript templates? That's what the src/main/resources/static directory is for. 

According to some documentation: "Although long-established standards like Java Server Pages (JSP) are still supported by Boot for legacy applications, most current applications either leverage more powerful view technologies supported by still-evolving and -maintained template engines or shift frontend development to a combination of HTML and JavaScript. It’s even possible to mix the two options successfully and play to each one’s strengths."

Comment: Good point @kenneth, will make changes as suggested, but still curious as to the behaviour of the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSP's are part of legacy Java Enterprise applications and are not the core of Spring Boot/MVC and it's more modern Template Engine approach (although Spring is based on Java EE). If you have any good reason to use JSP's, it could work. But with Spring, the MVC approach/implementation is to use the more modern template engines with technologies like **Thymeleaf**, **FreeMarker**, **Groovy Markup**, and **Mustache**.

*Question 1* If you have configured your pom.xml correctly, you can use different starters to configure how your application is deployed/run. JSP's are not a standard solution for Spring and should be configured seperately, it needs to be configured so that it will compile the JSP's into their respective location so that Tomcat reads it from the `webapps` folder. To compile and render JSP's your pom.xml needs both `spring-boot-starter-web` and `tomcat-embed-jasper` including the tag `<scope>provided</scope>`.

*Question 2* Spring comes with an **embedded Tomcat server** (spring-boot-starter-web). When you run `mvn spring-boot:run` it will start a Tomcat server and deploy your Spring Boot application on the Tomcat `localhost:8080`. `mvn clean`, before `spring-boot:run`, just deletes the output of a build by deleting the build directory.

*Question 3* Each .HTML template or .JSP file have their respective location in the project before compiling, so therefore some .JSP's are not compiled in your folders.

A Java Enterprise application and it's corresponding JSP's use a different project structure than Spring: All JSP's will be compiled from the "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/" if you have the right dependencies and run `spring-boot:run`. If you manually create a project, through compiling by cmd `-jar`, you should include your JSP's in the "*/webapp/*" folder and the Java.classes in *WEB-INF/classes/MyServlet.class*.

By using, for instance Thymeleaf (spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf), if you build your artifacts the IDE will compile templates from `/resources/templates` and work from there on your MVC project, where you can integrate your REST controllers seamlessly.

Tomcat stays pivotal in how your enterprise application is deployed, only that you need to adjust your project in Spring so that it will map and compile the right files into the .WAR before deploying.

My advice would be, for MVC, to use the template engines instead of the legacy JSP's. of course, there will use cases for JSP's inside a Spring project but it requires a differect structure and dependencies.

Comment: Thanks a lot @kenneth. Just one additional point if someone finds it useful `mvn package ` command builds a jar/war as defined in the pom.xml file if using maven which can then be run using jar command. However a few spring boot dev tools might not work with this way. Hence I find it better to run using `mvn spring-boot:run`.